# How quickly will bread yeast take to create an ethanol concentration of....?

Tags: yeast, first-time-brewer, bread

How quickly will bread yeast take to create and ethanol concentration of ~15%~,~10% and ~5%~ in at 30°C.I believe bread yeast is designed to rapidly fement(at first at least) but is not that ethanol tolerent so will progressively slow down as the ethanol concentration climes.I appologise if a similar thread has been posted already somewhere else on here by somebody else.
NOTE:I am not asking for a precise answer just a rough estimation from experience even  from wine yeast.

Comment: Maybe it's not your answer but I've tried to brew beer with baking yeast from non alcoholic beer! I tried two times and gain even less than 5%, but my friend with another breed yeast (a french yeast in a blue container which I don't know the name) reached to approximately 8%. So I'm gonna to try once again with his yeast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if any bakers yeast that is tollerant to much more than 5% Alcohol By Volume.

Hypothetically: A fermentable solution can fully attenuate in a matter of hours with enough adapted yeast and oxygen. But will never exceed the ABV tollerance of the strian.